# How to configure a FTP Server on a Windows Server 2008 for different users(folders)

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis, ftp

I've some questions about to configure a FTP on a windows server 2008 .

I've already everything installed.

I need to have to login which have access to different folder(depending on the user/group).

So, out-of-the-box, I didn't succeed to configure different folder depending on the user.

So I created two sites, one for each login, and I give the corrects rights to each other. But since I've only one IP and one incoming port, I've to set a different virtual host for each server(otherwise it seems that the second FTP site cannot starts).

But now the problem I've is that I need to specify once the server(ex `ftp1.myhost.com`), and once the virtual host in the user:

```
ftp1.myhost.com|myUserA
```

(See [here](http://www.cfexecute.com/post/quick-note-about-iis-7-5-ftp-virtual-hosts/) for more info)

I feel this like so dirty, redundant. So is there anyway to avoid:

1. To set different virtual host
2. If not, to not have this virtualHost to specify within the user field

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use User Isolation to do this. It's in the management console, there's a button labeled "FTP User Isolation". Just do that; I think you're over-thinking it.

Comment: I made it! And I used Virtual directories to point LocalUser/myUser to the right directory. Im curious if it's possible to have all users of one group that can have access to directory A and all users of another group acess to directory B, without configuring all those virtualdirectory

Answer (score 0):

A quick solution would be [CrushFTP](http://www.crushftp.com)  It easily does this and much more.  Very low cost and great support even during the free evaluation.